# Processing Point Management

Tags: processing, point

I'm making a simple Processing program that creates a certain amount of points that randomly move and then when the mouse is clicked the points move to the mouse's location.

I made the points as ellipses so they'd be easier to see.

```
//number of points
int ptnum=2;
//list of points
Point[] points=new Point[ptnum];

//class to create points
class Point
{
  float xpos;
  float ypos;

  //constructor
  Point(float x, float y){
    xpos=x;
    ypos=y;
  }

  //return x-coordinate  
  float ptx(){
    return xpos;
  }
  //return y-coordinate
  float pty(){
    return ypos;
  }

  //points randomly moving
  void randMove(){
     xpos+=random(-2,2);
     ypos+=random(-2,2);
  }

  //display points
  void display(){
    fill(0);
    ellipse(xpos,ypos,2,2);
  }

  //move points to mouse
  void move(){
    if(xpos>mouseX){
      xpos-=1;
    }
    if(ypos>mouseY){
      ypos-=1;
    }
    if(ypos<mouseY){
      ypos+=1;
    }
    if(xpos<mouseX){
      xpos+=1;
    }
  }
}


void setup(){
  size(640,360);

  //create ptnum of points
  for(int i=0; i<ptnum; i++){
    points[i]=new Point(random(1,width-1),random(1,height-1));
  }
}

//each point to random move
void randomMovement(){
  for(int i=0; i<ptnum; i++){
    points[i].randMove();
  }
}

//each point to display
void ptDisplay(){
  for(int i=0; i<ptnum; i++){
    points[i].display();
  }
}

//each point to move
void ptMove(){
  for(int i=0; i<ptnum; i++){
    points[i].move();
  }
}

void draw(){
  //start
  background(255,255,255);
  noFill();
  ptDisplay();
  //==========

  //if mouse clicked, move points to mouse XandY, if not-randommove
  if(mousePressed){
    ptMove();
  }
  else{
    randomMovement();
  }
}
```

I'm trying to make it so that the points can also interact with each other, for instance, they can't touch each other. Could someone help me figure this out? I'm having a bit a brain fart on this one. And if anyone has suggestions for the code, I'd be happy to hear them.

Thanks so much for the help, its appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Just calculate each point's location inside draw function.
Then, run a for loop to see if you have any collisions.
Since draw function is running many times per second, the result will be good enough.

When you have a collision, you can change each point's direction by 180 degrees.